# Can not show contributes I made to a project that I mirrored in GitHub

Tags: github

I and my teammates worked on a project. The project was on one of my teammate's github page. After finishing project I forked the project to my github page but when I prepared github readme stats, even though there were thousands of Java code, there were no Java in most used languages. You can see here

[image: 1]

I have mirrored the project, however, when I do that, not only java is not seen in most used languages, but also the contributes I made to the project have been deleted from contributes table from my page. What should I do?

Comment: Either it's a problem with GitHub, in which case you should contact the support. Otherwise, we can only look into the crystal ball. Maybe you can share the link to your repository?

Comment: Java has been added to the most used languages, however, contributions I made still have not been added to the contributions table. Here is the link: https://github.com/mustafayasar28/Monopoly-Project

Comment: I guess the contributions are not verified, when I enter the insights->contributors and click myself, I see that the commits are not verified. How can I make them verified?

Comment: Maybe the statistics are only updated after one day? I would assume so and look again tomorrow.